# Spring main class not scanning components

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Im having the same problem in every project that i start, i've checked my project structure, recreated, using Spring intlizr, STS4, i've checked application.properties configuration, dependencies, looked thousands of stack overflow questions, asked to GTP, prayed, but NOTHING work, im about to give up Spring

my components appearently arent being scanned

application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todos?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = pass

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Entity :

```
package com.badas.todo.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "taks")
public class Tasks {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String task;
    
    @Column
    private Boolean completed;
    
    @Column
    private String comment;

    public Tasks(String task, Boolean completed, String comment) {
        super();
        this.task = task;
        this.completed = completed;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Tasks() {
        super();
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public Boolean getCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }

    public void setCompleted(Boolean completed) {
        this.completed = completed;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

structure :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUsai.png)

Im trying to create a table but even if i try to broke my code, by doing something like

public Task(){
}

to

public TaskASLKFHASDFUOPGIJEHABSIFUPAHSBFUOIASHBFOIUASHBFouaidgf(AAAAAAAAAAA){
}

Spring server still running without broke

Comment: do you start off with a SpringApplication annotated class?

Comment: Yes .. 
package com.badas.todo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ToDoApp4TryApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ToDoApp4TryApplication.class, args);
 }

}

Comment: don't put code in comments, that's beyond unreadable. edit your question and add it in there

Answer (score 1):

SpringBoot 101: SpringBoot scans for components starting from the directory where the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` is and going from that directory down. **IT DOES NOT LOOK FOR SIBLING OR PARENT directories** (unless you tell him explicitly the package to look for with `@ComponentScan` annotation)

Solution: put you `ToDoApp4TryApplication` class in the top directory, and all components in child directories.

---

Alternatively use `@ComponentScan` under `@SpringBootApplicaiton` annotation to specify packages for components:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foo.bar", "com.foo.car"})`